# WebMethod gives Method not allowed, yet WebGet works

Tags: rest, wcf-rest

This works (with test in browser/debug):

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet]
string GetData(int value);
```

And this

```
[OperationContract]
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)]
string GetData(int value);
```

gives "Method Not Allowed".

Can someone enlighten me on this?

Comment: `[OperationContract]` and `[WebMethod]` can't be used together.

Comment: Hi John, If I use only [WebMethod] I get "endpoint not found"

Comment: So, this is a WCF service? Then don't use `[WebMethod]` at all.

Comment: Trying to understand RESTful services, so I want it to be just REST.

Comment: Then don't use `[WebMethod]` or `[ScriptMethod]`

Comment: Are you suggesting just use WebGet and WebInvoke?  Wondering why WebGet works just fine, but WebMethod gives an error.  Are they all part of the REST strategy?

Comment: No, **DON'T USE WEBMETHOD or SCRIPTMETHOD** they are part of the older ASMX technology.

Comment: Also, you might want to look into the ASP.NET Web API. Some developers find it more "REST" than WCF REST support.

Answer (score 0):

For Restful WCF service use either:
 [WebGet] or [WebInvoke] attributes.

Please ask if need more explanation.